# SSL_ERROR_WEAK_SERVER_CERT_KEY - a workaround?

Tags: curl, ssl-certificate

I have to access an oldish appliance via a web interface:

```
bash-4.2# curl -0 -v -k -u ADMIN:ADMIN https://10.130.1.1/redfish/v1
* About to connect() to 10.130.1.1 port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 10.130.1.1...
* Connected to 10.130.1.1 (10.130.1.1) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* NSS error -12156 (SSL_ERROR_WEAK_SERVER_CERT_KEY)
* The server certificate included a public key that was too weak.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) The server certificate included a public key that was too weak.
bash-4.2# curl -v -k -u ADMIN:ADMIN https://10.130.1.1/redfish/v1
* About to connect() to 10.130.1.1 port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 10.130.1.1...
* Connected to 10.130.1.1 (10.130.1.1) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* NSS error -12156 (SSL_ERROR_WEAK_SERVER_CERT_KEY)
* The server certificate included a public key that was too weak.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) The server certificate included a public key that was too weak.
```

Running it through openssl, I can see:

```
...
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (512 bit)
...
```

There is no way I can change what comes from the server - so, is there a way to tell curl to just get on with it?

Answer (score 0):

try change following in openssl.cnf

```
[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0
```

see if this helps.